# Async http requests with ETag caching

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, http-caching

I'm currently using `Requests` with `CacheControl` in my project, and am trying to migrate to an async approach.

There seem to be lots of great options out there for making async http requests. `httpx`, trio's `asks`.. etc.

Unfortunately I've struggled to find any existing solutions that have ETag based request caching functionality.

Am I missing an option that's out there, or is this just a gap that hasn't been filled yet?

Comment: Yep, I am still looking for the same thing. Apparently there is a very old request to add support to python stdlib https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/59295